# Alterar estilo de elemento pai a partir do elemento filho com CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, css-hover

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se tem como alterar o background da div pai quando o elemento filho(img) ganhar foco do mouse(:hover)

```css
.pai{ 
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #ffb3b3;
        display: inline-flex;
 }
    
.filho{ 
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        display: inline-flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <img class="filho">
</div>
```

Comment: Ainda não mas é uma das features para o css4 http://css4.rocks/

Comment: ou seja, ainda não é possível realizar esse feito correto?

Comment: Somente com css não, caso queria, posso colocar uma solução com algumas linhas de javascript.

Comment: Obrigado por tirar a duvida, em js eu consigo, só queria saber se tinha como com CSS puro mesmo!

Comment: Aí sim! disponha.